# (Android) Is there a simple way in Firebase Database to get a node's position ranked by a child?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have a Firebase database in my Android App and structured as below:

```
{"firebase_db" : { 
"users" : {
  "user_uid_0" : {
    "name" : "name_0",
    "score" : 2000
  },
  "user_uid_1" : {
    "name" : "name_1",
    "score" : 3000
  },
  "user_uid_2" : {
    "name" : "name_2",
    "score" : 1000
  },
  "user_uid_3" : {
    "name" : "name_3",
    "score" : 4000
  },
  "user_uid_4" : {
    "name" : "name_4",
    "score" : 0
  }
}
}
}
```

and I would like to sort them by the child "score". However, I do not want an entire list as the return (which can be easily achieved using the orderByChild() and limitToLast() methods). Instead, I want to know at what place a specific node is when ranked by the child "score" in descending order. For example, if I give the input "user_uid_0", then it should return 3 (the 3rd place); if the input is "user_uid_2", then it should return 4 (the 4th place)

But, I could not find a way to achieve this in several lines of code. Until now, the only way I've come up with to solve this problem efficiently was write a cloud function on Firebase...  Is there any simpler way to do this?

Comment: You can add one more field for rank in users and then on basis of score add the rank and use it directly by a firebase cloud function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can solve this on user side. The simplest way I can think of is to query the database according to your needs to get all user objects. Add all this objects to a `map`, in which the `key` of the map is the `user id` and the `value` is the `position`. In the end, just iterate over the map and get the position according to your user id. That's it!

Comment: Thanks, but since my database is large, it is impracticable to download "all" objects from the user side. Or did I misunderstand it?

Comment: Without it, you cannot know a position because the position of an user id is related to all the others. So in order to know a specific position you need to know also the position of all the others. If you want to input an user id and see the positions, you need to do that. If you want another way, you can use RecyclerView and an adapter, implement a seach feature and get the position from the adapter. `adapter.getItem(position);`.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?

Comment: Everything's fine, and I've solved it according to your suggestions. Thank you!